# How to test an input that stores/updates the value in React state

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

This the component I am trying to unit test with React testing library

```
export const TextInput = ({ label, inputValue, setInputValue }) => {
  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        {label}
        <input
          type="text"
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={(event) => {
            setInputValue(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </label>
    </form>
  );
};
```

useState is used in the parent component and passed in to  as props.

How do i render this when it depends on the useState hook

Comment: I don't see where you're using the useState hook. You can just test this by changing the input programatically and see if setInputValue (which can be a jest fn) was called correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is probably this.

```
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { describe, expect, it } from "vitest";
import TextInput from "../../src/case/TextInput";

describe("TextInput", () => {
  it("work", () => {
    let inputValueOnFirstRender = undefined;
    let isCallbackCalled = false;

    const inputValue = 0;
    const setInputValue = () => {
      isCallbackCalled = true;
    };

    const { getByRole } = render(
      <TextInput inputValue={inputValue} setInputValue={setInputValue} />
    );

    inputValueOnFirstRender = getByRole("textbox").value;

    fireEvent.change(getByRole("textbox"), { target: { value: "1" } });

    expect(inputValueOnFirstRender).toBe("0");
    expect(isCallbackCalled).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

But at least what assertion do you want?

Exactly what functionality do you want to test?

Comment: Thank you I was confused how to test when the useState hook is used